# How to print the output of find command with tab delimited at beginning

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I Have tried the below command to print the output of a find command with tab delimited.

`echo -e "\t"; find /usr/live/class/$client_abbr -name "$line.cls" -exec grep '^#include' {} \;`

If the output contains n number of lines, only the first line is printed with tab delimited, and it was not applied to rest of the lines. Please let me know how could i modify the above command to have tab at front of all lines.

Comment: you could pipe through sed: `find ... | sed 's/^/\t/' `

Comment: My Spider Sense tells me it would also be possible to  remove the `echo -e "\t";` from the beginning, run the rest of the command, store the intermediate result (if necessary), and loop through it. Then for each line, `echo -e \t`. But, I like the regular expression approach.

Answer (score 3):

You will likely find piping to `xargs` more efficient than using `-exec`.  The extra quotes, `-type f` and `-print0` are respectively for safety, for specifying that you need a file (not a directory) and for enabling file names with embedded white space.  With the `grep` output piped to `sed` (attribution to *Fischer's* comment), you get what you need.

```
find "/usr/live/class/$client_abbr" -type f -name "$line.cls" -print0 |
    xargs -0 grep '^#include' |
    sed 's/^/\t/'
```

Comment: On the other hand, you don't *need* the non-standard `-print0` option to `find` or the non-standard `-0` option to `xargs`, or even `xargs` itself, if you use `find`'s `-exec` primary.  I'm not convinced that the efficiency gain from those justifies the clarity and standards-compliance losses.

Comment: @John - YMMV - for me the speed helps.  If Vishnu has few files to sift through, then the `-exec` (or `-execdir`) is sufficient.